# Where to find r.java in AS 3.6

Tags: android-studio

With my inquiry, i was watching this tutorial on YouTube for android dev and the presenter uses an older version of Android Studio. And here i am, i downloaded the newest release AS 3.6.3 (who wouldn’t want the newest version?). So the tutorial continues and it comes to a part where he is showing r.java and i cant find it in the version i am with.

Where can i find r.java in AS 3.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new Android Gradle Plugin generates the corresponding bytecode directly and does not make the intermediate `R.java` file.

Check this link for more information [Android Studio 3.6](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/02/android-studio-36.html)